# I need to update multiple rows of data with different values. which php loop or code i can use to implement the same?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update multiple rows of data with different values. which php loop or code i can use to implement the same?

here is the code which am using.

```
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count ( $_POST ['productname'] ) ; $i++ )  
{  
    $qry2 = "UPDATE invoice_transaction 
                SET inv_trans_item_qty='".$_POST['quantity'][$i].
                "',inv_trans_created_by='".$act_admin.
                "',inv_trans_created_on='".$date.
                "' WHERE inv_code='".$inv_code."'";

    $res2 = mysqli_query($cn,$qry2);
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: why are u rolling back that edit?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile am not getting the desired output. all entries are filled with a common value, the last entered number

Comment: Not enough code! Where does `$inv_code` come from for starters

Comment: Is `inv_code` a unique key on that table?

Comment: @RiggsFolly inv_code is getting from the previous page. and it is received in this page. am getting some values while executing this query. but, it is not the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can use form elements with names like `item[1][productname]`:

```
<input type="text" name="item[1][productname]" />
<input type="text" name="item[1][quantity]" />
<br/>
<input type="text" name="item[2][productname]" />
<input type="text" name="item[2][quantity]" />
```

Then on the server side you can loop over those arrays:

```
foreach ($_POST["item"] as $item)
{
    $productname = $item['productname'];
    $quantity = $item['quantity'];

    // do stuff with $productname and $quantity
}
```